# getting the sum of certain rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are years from 2008 to 2018 occurences of all.

I am trying to get the sum of the 'numCrimes' value for each of 'Major Category' in its row, and then calculating the maximum.

```
df
                                                           numCrimes
Year    Borough               Major Category    
2008    Barking and Dagenham    Burglary                    1819.0
                                Criminal Damage             3037.0
                                Drugs                       1541.0
                                Fraud or Forgery            1240.0
                                Other Notifiable Offences   269.0
                                Robbery                     671.0
                                Sexual Offences             212.0
                                Theft & Handling            5678.0
                                Violence Against the Person 5185.0

         Barnet                 Burglary                    3817.0
                                Criminal Damage             3048.0
                                Drugs                       1366.0
                                Fraud or Forgery            1379.0
                                Other Notifiable Offences   319.0
                                Robbery                     824.0
                                Sexual Offences             239.0
                                Theft & Handling            10243.0
                                Violence Against the Person 5095.0
```

an example of the output would be:

The total of all years for

```
Burglary = 35,800                
Criminal Damage  = 42,000          
Drugs = 13,000                 
Fraud or Forgery = 32,000           
Other Notifiable Offences = 15,000 
Robbery = 40,000                    
Sexual Offences = 12,000            
Theft & Handling = 60,000       
Violence Against the Person = 20,500
```

The Maximum type of Crime (Major Category) that occurs is Theft and Handling

...

So basically adding the numCrimes of each occurence of each 'Major Category'

Comment: So basically you are ignoring `Year` and `Borough`?  Then simply `df.groubpy('Major Category')['numCrimes'].sum()` should fit the bill. If you want the result as a `Series`, then add `.squeeze()` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a setup to generate the data in your example as a DataFrame (even though there is only one column). Then a simple `groupby` and `sum`.

```
# setup
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    [2018],
    ['Barking and Dagenham', 'Barnet'],
    ['Burglary', 'Criminal Damage', 'Drugs', 'Fraud or Forgery',
     'Other Notifiable Offences', 'Robbery', 'Sexual Offences',
     'Theft & Handling', 'Violence Against the Person'],
], names=['Year', 'Borough', 'Major Category'])

df = pd.DataFrame([
    1819, 3037, 1541, 1240, 269, 671, 212,
    5678, 5185, 3817, 3048, 1366, 1379,
    319, 824, 239, 10243, 5095], index=ix, columns=['numCrimes'],
)

# sum
total = df.groupby('Major Category').sum()

# top 4:
total.squeeze().sort_values(ascending=False).head(4)
```

**Output**:

```
Major Category
Theft & Handling               15921
Violence Against the Person    10280
Criminal Damage                 6085
Burglary                        5636
```